# Right way to establish push notifications for Android/iOS

Tags: android, ios, html, notifications

Assuming my application is based on HTML5/Jquery mobile (Cross platform web app),

- How is it possible to create push notifications for Android/iOS ?
- Also, does it include developing different "notifications engine" for
  each device? (in other words:  Do I need to implement two different background processes for each type of device?)

I'd be really glad to get a full answer/references to my conflict.

*I have searched for the forum's previous answers but it seems like the threads are quite old so i preferred opening my own question.*

Comment: Google and Apple both operate their own push notification service.

Comment: What are you using to build apps (phonegap, titanium...)?

Comment: What does it mean? Do I need to implement two different background processes for each type of device?

Comment: I'll probably use PhoneGap

Answer (score 0):

1)

- Apple has Apple Push Notification Service (APNS) to push out alerts.
  More details at
  https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/NetworkingInternet/Conceptual/RemoteNotificationsPG/Chapters/ApplePushService.html.
- Google offers a comparable Google Cloud  Messaging Service (GCM).
  Details at http://developer.android.com/google/gcm/index.html. **UPDATE:** GCM *does* support iOS as a client, **so can be used for both Android and iOS**, with some work. (Technically, it will be an APNS when it reaches the iOS device.)

2) Not sure I understand what you mean by "background processes", If you are referring to  backend service/originator of notifications,then the service needs to be able to communicate i with both the Apple APNS or Google CDM using the interfaces supported by these services and send out alerts in appropriate format. If you are looking for a third party service for sending out push notifications, you can checkout UrbanAirship or Parse which can send notifications to either platform.

Comment: By that u mean - when I  trigger either APNS/GCM to push some notification to the user device, does it require me to divide my development to separate executing parts depending on the device? Also, more technically what does it require? is it code on the server side/client? it sounds like a task which i want to run "in the background" to figure if a notification should be sent - this is the part im a bit confused of.

Comment: [I realize this is an old question. But others reading this later might have similar uncertainty.] @Popokoko - I think your confusion is that a "push notification" is something that a device *only* receives. So each device needs code appropriate to its OS. *Sending* the notification is done by your *server*.

Answer (score 0):

GCM is the Google Cloud Messaging Service for Android, while APNS is the push notification service for iOS, both of them are very similar.

If you're already using html5 and jQuery, I would suggest you to use Phonegap which is a framework that allows you to create mobile apps using only html5 css3 javascript(jQuery) it was very useful for me and they've a push notifications plugin which works for Android and iOS.

Be sure to check Phonegap and Phonegap Build (which is a very interesting service)

Regards

Comment: Hmm i see, I'd like to use phonegap but im not sure about if all the technologies i wanted to use would fit this matter, can i use html/jqmobile + node.js for the server side?

Comment: @Popokoko - Also consider using `php` on server side. [Useful discussion of pros and cons of php vs node.js](http://www.infoworld.com/article/2866712/php/php-vs-node-js-an-epic-battle-for-developer-mind-share.html). Even if you decide on `node.js`, this discussion may help you be aware of what solutions you may need on server side - so you can go to some `node.js` forum and say "php people use XYZ to do ABC, what is a similar solution in `node.js`?"